# stripe-cli always return 401

Tags: docker, stripe-payments

I am trying to use **stripe-cli** in **linux command line** on my local environment which is inside a **docker container** but always i get a **401** when trying to reach the webhook.

The payment type is sofort.

I can see that the keys are registered in stripe dashboard. What am I doing wrong?

> login

```
stripe login --interactive
Enter your API key: 
Your API key is: sk_test_******************************kv6Q
How would you like to identify this device in the Stripe Dashboard? [default: XXXX] 
> Done! The Stripe CLI is configured for xxxx.com with account id acct_1Fb.........23u
```

> listener

```
stripe listen --forward-to https://xxxxx.local:30443/webhooks/charges --skip-verify
> Ready! Your webhook signing secret is whsec_BzBp8LT...............2xEk (^C to quit)
2019-12-29 06:34:23   --> source.chargeable [evt_1Fuu............l]
2019-12-29 06:34:23  <--  [401] POST https://xxxx.local:30443/webhooks/charges [evt_1Fuu............Zl]
2019-12-29 06:34:25   --> charge.pending [evt_1Fuu..................BH7gS]
2019-12-29 06:34:25  <--  [401] POST https://xxxx.local:30443/webhooks/charges [evt_1FuuQ0Iq..................S]
```

Comment: Did you run the listener docker with -p 30443:30443 ?

Comment: I don't think this works for docker v2